# Sendmail config

Tags: server, sendmail

I need to configure Sendmail server using ubuntu, and I get error permission denieded even if I am connected as a root :

Here is the error message
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGpIG.png

Answer (score 0):

`/sendmail/mail/sendmail.mc` **IS NOT** (and should not be) an executable file.

To convert/compile `sendmail.mc` file into `sendmail.cf` file in `/etc/mail` directory execute `m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10359510/2139766